# How to split a sentence and get only left 15 or less (Not greater than 15) characters on one column but at the end it could be a complete word

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

How to split a sentence and get only left 15 or less (Not greater than 15) characters on one column but it could be a complete word.

Example: `Ali, House Number ABC/123, Sattelite Town, Lahore.`

```
Column 01           Column 02           Column 03           Column 04
Ali, House          NumberABC/123,      Sattelite Town,     Lahore.
```

Need support here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(100) = 'Ali, House Number ABC/123, Sattelite Town, Lahore.'

SELECT LEFT(LEFT(@Str, 15) , 15 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(@Str, 15))) )
```

Comment: Thank you, but what about remaining columns?

Answer (score 0):

Improving @M.Ali solution:

```
declare @Str varchar(100) =
    'Ali, House NumberABC/123, Sattelite Town, Lahore.', @bit varchar(16)
declare @tb table (split varchar(15))

set @Str += ' '
while rtrim(@Str)>''
begin
    select  @bit = rtrim(left(left(@Str, 16),
                    16 - charindex(' ', reverse(left(@Str, 16))))),
            @Str = ltrim(substring(@str, len(@bit) + 1, 100))
    insert into @tb values (@bit)
end
select * from @tb
```